# Light Linux Distro For Android Dev

Tags: android, linux

i want to dive into Android development, specifically into custom ROM / Kernel development, except i don't know any good Linux distro to use.

Are there any lightweight or maybe even barebone minimalist Linux distros out there, that are up for the job? And it should be running a desktop environment.

Comment: I think a minimal Ubuntu would be a possible option.

Comment: Is there a reason you are asking for "lightweight of barebone" ? sounds like you have an extra requirement hidden in there (slow computer? low on disk space). Also, what would you mean by "good linux distro"? Any would probably enable you to do Android development, but some might need a different approach to isntaling your tools then others? Hard to answer like this I think.

Comment: @randomizer Ubuntu is not an option for me.

Comment: @Nanne well my computer isn't that good in the first place, besides i am a big fan of lightweight operating systems, i could of went with Ubuntu but it drives me nuts! Unity is really laggy on my PC and there are numerous features that i don't even use or know! And with a barebone system i can build it up to my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for lightweight and small i would go with raspian which is a debian branch, its been designed to be small and run lightweight since it is customed to the raspberry pi. powerful and small with a desktop.

Comment: Aren't there any alternatives, ones that are made with PC's in mind?

Comment: Debian would be my first go